# Catastrophic Failure EXCEL VBA - error '-2147418113 (8000ffff)'

Tags: excel, vba, connection-string

I am struggling to find relevant information on the

> 'run-time error '-2147418113 (8000ffff)' - Catastrophic Failure'

I am experiencing.

```
Sub GenerateAIA_Click()
Dim SQL_query, SQL_syntax, DB_path, setting_conn As String
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim query_rslt As New ADODB.Recordset

Dim mth, mth_yr As Variant
Dim dt As Date
Dim i, bol As Integer
Dim temp1, temp2 As Variant

dt = Sheets("Main").Range("C4")
mth_yr = MonthName(Month(Sheets("Main").Range("I12")), False) & " " & Year(Sheets("Main").Range("I12"))

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AIA").Select

DB_path = ThisWorkbook.FullName 'Refering the same workbook as Data Source
setting_conn = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DB_path & ";HDR=Yes';"
conn.Open setting_conn
SQL_syntax = "SELECT * FROM [Setup$]"   'Your SQL Statement (Table Name= Sheet Name=[Sheet1$])
query_rslt.Open SQL_syntax, conn
```

I have also noticed that this error is shown on the line

```
conn.Open setting_conn
```

I use excel 2016 and also my file format .xlsm
Anyone have idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your connection string has a problem. 
Here's how I got it to work:

(First make sure to add a reference to the Microsoft Active-X Data Objects Library)

[image]

```
Sub test()
  Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
  Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

  conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\PC\test.xlsm;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=NO"";"
  conn.Open

  rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", conn

  If Not rs.EOF Then
    MsgBox rs(0) ' display the value of the first field in the first row
  Else
    MsgBox "No records found."
  End If

  rs.Close
  conn.Close

End Sub
```

So take my example, change the filename to your XLSM file, and the sheet name to your sheet name (with a `$` added to the end of it)

If your sheet has header names in the first now, use `HDR=Yes`, and if not, `HDR=No`

Comment: after i add your code which mean i add "sub test", i got error 
run time error '3706' : 
Application-defined or object-defined error

but maybe in my opinion, i don't have reference to the microsoft active-x data object library. 
please confirm to me, if it's a mistake I don't have add ins on excel.

Comment: It's not an "add-in" - it comes with Office. In the VBA Editor, go to Tools... References... There is your list of references. You have to put a checkmark next to the ones you want to include.

Comment: but after i add microsoft active-x data object library, got error msg "name conflicts with existing module, project or object library. then i change references from microsoft activeX data objects 2.8 library to microsoft activeX data ojects 6.1 library. but still error with Catastrophic Failure - error '-2147418113 (8000ffff)'

Comment: i dont think use connection (this macros to SQL), because this macro just only convert value table to another table. but if i try to delete the connection code

make another problem, run-time error '3704' application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: It works fine for me, so you must not have changed the filename or the sheet name to the right thing. Try it in a brand new workbook all by itself instead of adding it to what you are currently using to make sure you can get it working first.

Comment: I take it you were able to get it to work then? If so, please remember to accept the answer so that it does not remain open.

Answer (score 0):

or you can change display resolution for your monitor